# Remove --parachain-id flag from zombienet

Tags: zombienet

I'm using zombienet v1.3.30.
My config file is like this:

```
[[parachains]]
id = 100
cumulus = true

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  chain_spec_path = "./bin/chain/specs/collatorSpecRaw.json"
  command = "./bin/chain/{{ZOMB_OS}}/parachain"
  ws_port = "{{ZOMB_WS_PORT}}"
```

I see that the parachain id is set with `id = 100` in the parachains heading, but my `parachain` node binary doesn't support the flag `--parachain-id` so it fails to launch the collator.

```
error: Found argument '--parachain-id' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
```

The para id is already in the chain spec, so I was wondering if there's a way to remove the flag rather than override it?
Otherwise I guess I'll have to try older zombienet versions or rebuild the current one without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the flag for the parachain is `cumulus_based`. Should work with this config.

Thanks!!

```
[[parachains]]
id = 100
cumulus_based = true

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  chain_spec_path = "./bin/chain/specs/collatorSpecRaw.json"
  command = "./bin/chain/{{ZOMB_OS}}/parachain"
  ws_port = "{{ZOMB_WS_PORT}}"
```

Comment: ah shoot. How obvious, ty.

Comment: Thanks! You really help!